# Why console show me that jquery has no method 'live'

Tags: jquery

Today I find a method to use jQuery:live, I write an example to try it.
I use the eg from api.jquery.com,but through the chrome console,I find that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'
```

Maybe you think it is easy,but to me, I don't understand this.So I need help after searching the engine google.help me!

the code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('body').append('<a href="http://baiud.com" class="sina">yahoo</a>');
      $('a.like').live("click", function(){ 

          alert("hello"); 
         return false; }
       ) 
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" class="google">echo hellow</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And http://jsfiddle.net/huapei/9C9sF/ is my code there.

Comment: coz it has no method live! http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 4):

That method is currently <strike>obsolete</strike> removed, use the `on` method.

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9C9sF/1/

Comment: it's not only "currently" obsolete, it has been removed entirely from version 1.9 ...

Comment: the Tutorials in my hand is old

Answer (score 4):

Live is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+ and removed in 1.9 you should consider using .on() instead

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Thanks, the Tutorials is old

Answer (score 1):

this method is deprecated in version 1.9. If you wan't to use it you have to install the jquery migrate plugin